# Browser development?

Tags: browser

I'm wondering, how can I develop application/plugin/browser extension that can extend functionality of search engine, like McAfee SiteAdviser puts green checks or red crosses on Google page when it thinks the web-site is 'clean'

Comment: Which browser do you want to develop for?

Comment: let us say, IE Mozilla and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference

You get access to the DOM and can do stuff to it.

Comment: should it be a plugin for a browser that extends functionality of Search Engine?

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer Development site is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ie/.